# Cambiar el logo del header en diferentes paginas ¿? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo una duda, quiero cambiar el logo del header en diferentes URL's en wordpress, por ejemplo, un logo en CONTACTO, otro en ACERCA DE, otro en SERVICIOS y he construido este código pero no funciona muy bien, de hecho no funciona, no cambia la imagen. Esta es la URL que estoy validando en el código de abajo: https://mipagina.com/daewoo

```
function change_logo_on_single($html) {

   if(is_page('daewoo')){
      $html = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)\/>/', '<img src="https://mipagina.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/serv_03.png" class="custom-logo" alt="" itemprop="logo" />', $html);
   }

   return $html;
}

add_filter('get_custom_logo','change_logo_on_single');
```

Comment: El código funcionaría bien, si es que la función del tema que inserta el logo, efectivamente usa ese filtro, pero muchos temas no te dan esa flexibilidad. Revisa el stack de llamadas que se hace en el header, capaz que hasta un echo de la URL de imagen es lo que hace sin usar la función nativa de WP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiza no sea la respuesta más elaborada, pero me funciona para lo que debia hacer.

¿Es dificil? NO

Realmente debes buscar el ID de la web y el ID de la imagen, ¿Como?

Clic derecho, INSPECCIONAR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el id de la imagen se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación dejo el código que cambia el logo dependiendo la página.

```
.page-id-150 #logo {
    content: url(https://reparaciondelineablancacdmx.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/logo-mabe-2.png);
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
function change_logo_on_single() {

   if(is_page('daewoo')){
      echo '<img src="https://mipagina.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/serv_03.png" class="custom-logo" alt="" itemprop="logo" />';
   }
}

add_filter('get_custom_logo','change_logo_on_single');
```